# mod rewrite directory if file/folder not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a folder named "folder1" in my root directory

**www.domain.com/
www.domain.com/folder1**

I need to redirect all the requests to www.domain.com that turn up to be a 404 error, to folder1. Like so:

**www.domain.com/a_file.txt**

If a_file.txt doesn't exist, look in folder1:

**www.domain.com/folder1/a_file.txt**

I want this to work the same for subdirectories, like so:

**www.domain.com/a_folder** (redirect if it doesn't exist in the root)

**www.domain.com/folder1/a_folder**

I know I should use RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-f but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 20):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) folder1/$1 [L,R]
```

- The first rewrite-cond ensures you do not loop (in case the file does not exist inside folder1 either
- The second one checks that target is not a file
- The third - that it is not a folder either
- And, finally, rewrite the url. `L` flag means this is the last rule applied (even if there are rules after it), `R` means redirect. You can also add `QSA` flag if you want any query-string parameters passed to the original be sent to the new url

Comment: Exactly was I was writing... +1 for the loop avoid and explanations.