# Mod rewrite redirection to another domain if file not exist

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

#### What I'm trying to do:

I need to redirect a request to a file to another domain if the file not exists. For example:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/js/foo.js
```

redirects to (if not exists)

```
http://www.myanotherdomain.com/js/foo.js
```

#### What I do:

I wrote the next lines at the end the htaccess, but they redirect ALL!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myanotherdomain.com/$1 [L,NC]
```

Before these lines, I have a lot of lines like this (I'm using MVC (Model, View,Controller)):

```
RewriteRule ^car/brand/?$ ?controller=Car&action=viewBrand [L,NC]
```

#### What happens:

It works wells with non existing files, but seems to be imcompatible with the MVC rules. These rules have to match and then stop evaluating rules because de "L" flag. But it seems to continue evaluation of the rules and finally evaluates the redirect rule. The result is this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/car/brand/
```

goes to

```
http://www.myanotherdomain.com/?controller=Car&action=viewBrand
```

*Please can anyone help me?*

*Thank you very much,*

*Jonathan*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myanotherdomain.com/$1 [QSA,R,L]
```

See also: [mod rewrite directory if file/folder not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076385/mod-rewrite-directory-if-file-folder-not-found)

Comment: Thanks for the super-fast answer, but the result is the same :S

Comment: just changed it try again, im not an expert but ill try my best to help :) maybe that article i linked might be of more help

Answer (score 0):

Try placing these rules **after** your MVC rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(js|png|jpe?g|gif|css|html?)$ http://www.myanotherdomain.com/$1.$2 [L,R,NC]
```

If you want all requests, and not just static content like scripts and images then change the `RewriteRule` line to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myanotherdomain.com/$1 [L,R,NC]
```