# htaccess redirect to index

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Basically, i'm trying to redirect all the pages like this

```
http://www.example.com/page-test-1/page-test-1-2/page-test-1-2-3.html
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/page-test-1/page-test-1-2.html
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/page-test-1/page-test-1-2/
```

to the home page :

```
http://www.example.com/
```

Here's what I've trying :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.exmaple.com/([^.]+)/
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.exmaple.com/ [QSA,L,R=301]
```

And here's the tester I'm using : http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ 
Any way I can do this ? Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you just trying to redirect everything to the home page?

Comment: No I'm lefting only pages `http://www.example.com/page-test-1.html`

Comment: So redirect everything except for `http://www.example.com/anypage.html`?

Comment: That's exaclty what I want!

Comment: Maybe duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748813/mod-rewrite-redirection-to-another-domain-if-file-not-exist

Comment: I don't think so ! Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: %{HTTP_HOST} only captures the host, not the folders or files, so it will never match ^www.exmaple.com/([^.]+)/.

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exmaple\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page-test-1/.+ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will catch anything that is not `/anypage.html` and redirect it. You need to set the `RewriteCond` on the `REQUEST_URI` not the `HTTP_HOST`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([^/]*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/ [QSA,L,R=301]
```