# .htaccess won't stop rewriting when ajax request is made

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I'm having great difficulty making it so .htaccess will stop rewriting the url in a ajax call..

my .htaccess below:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1&task=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1&task=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1&task=$2&id=$3&data=$4&key=$5
```

and the PHP ajax call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".checkButton").click(function () {
            var objID = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/update.php",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {val: objID},
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    alert("sucess" + data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert(textStatus + errorThrown + jqXHR);


 }
        });
    });
});
```

Because of an existing large amount of code I don't want to change the rewrite rules we have in place already but find a way in which I can ignore the rewrite rules for only a ajax request. I have been searching around for a while and I only managed to find suggestions of using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
```

edit:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1&task=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1&task=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1&task=$2&id=$3&data=$4&key=$5
```

Revised .htaccess ajax is still unable to find the page after testing.

Comment: Missing flags in htaccess for existing files/directories. rewrite should not be done if file/directory requested exists

Comment: Could you possibly show me an example or link me to the relevant material I'm eager to learn more and I don't quite understand right now.

Comment: The files used in the rewriting rules do actually exist in this case but they are being used by PHP includes based on what is being passed in by the querystrings if that helps further?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076385/mod-rewrite-directory-if-file-folder-not-found Look at the `-f` and `-d` flags. Note I am not an htaccess expert...only know enough to be dangerous but know that this is very very common when it comes to virtual directories/paths

Comment: I updated my question, I'm presuming this is how I would add more conditions before rewriting

Comment: These rules aren't relevant for the Ajax call. If the Ajax request really is rewritten, then there must be other rules somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteCond` works just for the first `RewriteRule` just after.

Use instead:

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} =XMLHttpRequest
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1&task=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1&task=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?system=$1&task=$2&id=$3&data=$4&key=$5 [L]
```